# Creating a new column based on filteration on datetime column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column by filtering on another column in a dataset.

```py
df.loc[df.APP_DATE >= '2016-01-01' & df.APP_DATE <= '2017-12-31', 'TAG_data'] = 'TRAIN'
```

for this daterange my new column 'TAG_data' should have value = TRAIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `()` because [operator precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html):

```
df.loc[(df.APP_DATE >= '2016-01-01') & (df.APP_DATE <= '2017-12-31'), 'TAG_data'] = 'TRAIN'
```

Or use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df.loc[df.APP_DATE.between('2016-01-01', '2017-12-31'), 'TAG_data'] = 'TRAIN'
```